# FAIL_ON_UNKOWN_PROPERTIES not working as expected on Jersey POST

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

Using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693669/how-to-post-a-json-object-to-a-jax-rs-service) as a reference I put together a bare bones Jersey controller method for POST calls that looks like this:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createVisit(Visit newVisit) {
    LOGGER.info("Creating visit");

    this.visits.add(newVisit);

    return Response.ok(newVisit)
            .build();
}
```

Here are the fields on my Visit object (constructors and getter/setters omitted because I don't think they're relevant here - I can add them in if they'd be helpful):

```
public class Visit {
  private VisitId id;
  private AthleteId athleteId;
  private CustomerId customerId;
  private StoreId storeId;

  private Instant createdUtc;
  private Instant lastModifiedUtc;

}
```

When I pass in valid Visit object fields in JSON format in the request body, I see the Visit object successfully populated in the response as expected.  However, if I add fields that aren't part of the Visit object to the request body they seem to be ignored.

I've seen a number of posts trying to figure out how to disable the `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` property, but I seem to be having the opposite issue.  My understanding is that `FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES` defaults to true, but in that case I would expect to get an error response code (500?) when the JSON object in the request body doesn't match with the object I'm passing in to my POST method. Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `ContextResolver`, as mentioned in [the documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson)

```
@Provider
public class MyObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MyObjectMapperProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
            return mapper;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to make sure the resolver is registered. If you are using some scanning mechanism to auto-register your resources and providers, this class should be picked up with the `@Provider` annotation

Comment: Should I still need to do this if I want FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES set to true?  I think I remember seeing that is the default setting (couldn't find the link just now though).  Do I still need to add a ContextResolver to explicitly set that value to true?

Comment: [default is true](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html#FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES) - to fail

Comment: Thanks for the link - so considering that it is enabled by default shouldn't I be getting a `JsonMappingException` when I hit this endpoint with a request body that doesn't match with my Visit object?

Comment: It should. Are you sure you're using Jackson? Can you confirm Jackson is being used? Do you have any other providers in your project that might have precedence? And a `@JsonProperty` with a different  name and see if it works when serializing.

Comment: Ah, I think that's my issue there - looks like we aren't using Jackson at the moment.  I don't see any reason why we can't though, so I'll try adding that in and go from there.  Thanks for the help!