# post an input value from AngularJS to json rest webservice (jaxb java)

Tags: java, html, angularjs, json, jaxb

After posting the input values in the url I need, I have to add those values to my web service that I created using java (JAXB). I followed this [Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-formparam-example/) to discover the @FormParam annotation but I am not really sure whether I can use it or not in my case since I am working with AngularJS and I saved the input value in my controller. My question is: How to set the variable "stack" in my web service (json). I tested wether the POST method is working or not using a system.out.println() and it works perfectly with my java code. I will appreciate your help. Thank you.

```js
function myController($scope,$http){
    $scope.save = function() {
        var data=$scope.stack;
  
        /* post to server*/
        $http.post(url, data).then(function(response){
          // success callback
        }, function(response){
          // failure callback
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<form ng-submit="save()">
    <input ng-model="stack"></input>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
    <p>Your comment:<span ng-bind="stack"></span></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need **@FormParam** in your case(for post methods). You can directly bind a whole object ( stack object ) in **jaxrs** service. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693669/how-to-post-a-json-object-to-a-jax-rs-service) question could help !!