# Adding JSON as a message body in a HTTP PUT request in Cygwin?

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, curl

I have the following `JSON` , which I have validated using [JsonLint](http://jsonlint.com/) :

```
{
        "names": [
            {
                "id":"123",
                "name":"stubName",
                "type":"stubType",
            }
        ]
    }
```

I would like to add it as a message body in my `CURL` command (using `Cygwin`) in order to test a REST handler that I wrote.

I am currently using this command, which I created from reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body):

```
 curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{
        "names": [
            {
                "id":"123",
                "name":"StubName",
                "type":"StubType",
            }
        ]
    }' localhost:9980/Id/123/version/123/addPerson
```

My handler is as follows:

```
            @PUT
            @Consumes("application/json")
            @Path("/Id/{Id}/version/{version}/addPerson")
            public Response addPerson(@PathParam("Id") String Id,
                                                    @PathParam("version") String version, 
                                                     @Context List<Name> names) {

            LOGGER.info("NAMES PASSED : {}", names.toString());

    }
```

When I try to hit my method using CURL I get an `HTTP 400` method.

Edit: when I try to do names.toString() I get a null pointer, meaning that the names list must be null.

Comment: `{}` are not valid characters in a url

Comment: I'd suggest you try using the Postman app instead of cURL too

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry I added that by mistake, please see the actual path I am using

Comment: I don't know what json library you've setup, but the `@Context` is intended for the request object, not the json document. Like, look at some of these examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693669/how-to-post-a-json-object-to-a-jax-rs-service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should not use `@Context` The entity body (parameter) should be annotation-less.

   ```
    public Response addPerson(@PathParam("Id") String Id,
                              @PathParam("version") String version, 
                              List<Name> names) {
   ```
2. With a `List<Name>` you should be sending a JSON array. Get rid of the `{"names":`, and just send the `[]`

   ```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '[
       {
           "id":"123",
           "name":"StubName",
           "type":"StubType",
       }
   ]' localhost:9980/Id/123/version/123/addPerson
   ```

Comment: Thanks, please give the example code changes in an answer,