# Restful web service throws servlet.init() exception

Tags: java, web-services, rest, servlets, jax-rs

Here is my restful webservice which is having multiple methods declared in it.
When I declare both methods i.e GET and POST it throws `servlet.init()` exception.
Here is the root cause of exception:

> com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: Fatal issues found at class rest.DatabaseOperations. See logs for more details.

But when I declare only post method it works perfectly.

```
@Path("/databaseOperation")
public class DatabaseOperations {


@Path("/select")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String select(String data) {
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Path("/insert")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void insert(String feed) {
    } catch (Exception exception) {
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your `try{}` block ?

Comment: try block is there, I just forgot to put it over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A GET method does not contain a payload, therefore this annotation is incorrect

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
```

You probably need something similar to

```
@Path("/select")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String select(@QueryParam("data")String data) {
```

Note: I assumed that  missing `try` is a typo

Comment: but i have to send data through angularJS from web page. So how would I'll get it here?

Comment: A `GET` request sends data using query parameters in URL `yourserver.com/select?data=xxxx`. If you need to send JSON to your server use a `POST` request. Also you probably will need to parse JSON at server side. Change `String` parameter with a bean. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693669/how-to-post-a-json-object-to-a-jax-rs-service